# Measure the length of the mesh

Tags: unity, mesh

I have a boat race game. I have a curved mesh, that is the track.
How can I measure the map(mesh) length, so I can place checkpoints on every 1/5 of the length?

Comment: Can you include a picture of the wireframe of the mesh?

Comment: you can use ```Mesh``` in an c# script to get ```vertices``` of the mesh and then sum the distances between every two vertices placed in the direction of movement, which adds up to the whole distance you want.

Comment: @MohammadZamanian can you set up the answer, so I can select your variant as the right one?

Comment: @GuardFromUA Do you need the code or should I just add my comment as an answer?

Comment: @MohammadZamanian it would be cool with code for sure.